# WPF, Different UserControl Navigation on the same TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

http://s7.directupload.net/images/140511/66z6w2tq.jpg

As you can see on the picture I am explaining everything with a Schema, I have a TabItem and on this TabItem I want to change the DataContext everytime with a Button. What I mean,is that I want to navigate through different UserControls but to stay on the same TabItem from a TabControl. I dont know how to Navigate through different ViewModels and everytime my values not to change from my Elements. I also could not find an Example of the same situation. Any Help with a Code Snippet or a full example will be appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

WPF/MVVM

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good case for using pub sub with `EventAggregator` or MvvmLight's Messenger.

You can then loosly coupled notify the `MainViewModel` to exchange controls or views within a tab. 
Basically you can notify another `ViewModel` with another scope to do certain changes and then subscribe to it.

A possible structure could be:
- A MainViewModel with a collection of TabItemViewModels
- A single TabItemViewModel could contain also Controls and nested ViewModels

If you want to change a tab send a ChangeTabMessage to the MainViewModel
If you want to navigate within a tab use also Messaging or navigate as you do today.

Check out the EventAggregator here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

or check out MVVMligh Toolkit Messenger ...

HTH